# Laravel 5.2: Mutators - How to combine two columns into one with mutators

Tags: php, laravel-5, mutators

I have a column as `contact` in my DB. on the form, I am also displaying the country-code and then user inputs his contact number.

As in DB I have single column, I want to set a mutator so that, I can concatenate `countryCode-ContactNumber` and save to the DB.

What I had written in my User model is:

```
public function setContactAttribute($value)
{
    // $this->attributes['contact'] = $this->attributes['country'].'-'.$value;
    $this->attributes['contact'] = $this->country.'-'.$value;
}
```

This is not working!!.
Can we add more then two fields in L5.2 Mutators?
Many thanks.

Comment: How do fill your model with data?

Comment: sorry!! i didn't got what u r trying to say @Skysplit. I user Create method on user model.

Comment: Do you use `Model::fill()` or do it other way?

Comment: I use Create method on User mode. like ``User::Create($request->all());``

Comment: Probably `country` field is not present in model data when `contact` field is being mutated. When the model is created, does your `contact` field look like `-{contactValue}`?

Comment: By model data, if you mean in my ``$fillable`` property, then NO, in that I haven't defined ``country``, as no column in DB. When I ``dd`` my request, i do get contact field as ``contact``. Let me know if I misunderstood anything!

Comment: Then that's the problem :) Your model does not have `country` data because this field is not fillable (your model is not filled with this value when you're calling `Model::create()`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121934/discussion-between-tarunn-and-skysplit).

Answer (score -1):

Use Request in your mutator function

`public function setContactAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['contact'] = Request::input('country').'-'.$value;
}`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This uses the country value from the request, the question is if it's possible to use a value from another field, set on this instance.

Comment: Yes Possible. you have to access the value using "$this".